# Show File size in RTE Text in TYPO3 7.6

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-7.x, fal

The extension `ml_links` is not supported anymore.

Which is the recommended way to automatically display a file's size and type for links to files made in the RTE?

I'm not referring to fluid templating for a FAL link, just regular RTE text that's output via fluid_styled_content or:

```
<f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="lib.parseFunc_RTE">{data.bodytext}</f:format.html>
```

Comment: To output the size automatically you should edit the lib.parseFunc_RTE typoscript rendering of "link"-Tags which comes from the RTE and append or add the size to the title link of the resulting a-tag.